# If f is Riemann integrable on [a,b] then prove that there is an equispaced partition Pn such that limU(Pn,f) = limL(Pn,f) = the value of the integral.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I have already proved that if f is Riemann integrable then there is a sequence of partitions whose upper and lower sums converge to the integral. I'm unable to produce the same result for an equispaced partition Pn. [image]

Comment: If it is [Riemann integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_integral) then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a mesh size $\delta$ such that if the partition has smaller mesh size than $\delta$ then the Riemann sum is closer than $\epsilon$ to the integral. Then mesh size of uniform partitions is $1/n$, which tends to zero. So, they eventually get smaller than any required $\delta$.

Comment: The title makes no sense. Do you mean a *sequence* of such partitions?

Comment: yes! @andres E Caicedo